# Java solution to execute SQL scripts (in Git) in required order

Tags: java, mysql, github, mariadb

Given:
A project in Git hub has folder structure like (Tables, Views, Functions, Procedures). Each folder has SQL script files in it (.sql)

Todo:
Need to create a JAR file where

1) I can Specify DB details

2) Specify the order of scripts to be executed (Ex: 1)Tables, 2)Views, 3)Functions, 4)Procedures). "Table" folder has ".sql" files in it to create tables. Need to set the order of tables to be executed to avoid referential integrity issues.

3) And pick the script file in specified order & run it against Maria/Mysql DB to create tables, views etc.

Ex: Specify the order in XML/JSON/text file/ArrayList/anything & execute script files in that order.

NOTE: Order is important, as tables should be created before views etc.

Comment: Your question is very broad, and would require a lot of code to completely answer.  It would be better for you to ask something more specific.

Comment: Java solution to specify the order of folder/sql files to be read & execute them in the specified order.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried searching the internet? Are you expecting us to write full solution for you or find you a resource that does it? This question looks off-topic to me either way. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Git is only concerned with the files on disk. Al the rest is your job

Comment: Alex, I searched. I have a general way to do. set the files names in ArrayList in the required order. iterate list & execute .sql in Java.

But I want a better approach. like specfy the order in XML/JSON & execute accordingly.

Need a solution but not the full code, as I want to give try myself first with the solutions proposed here. Tahnk you

Comment: Well, based on how broad your question still is, I'd recommend reading into using JDBC as well as the DOM parser built in the Java stdlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you use an existing tool like [Liquidbase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) to define your SQL as a set of database migrations. You can use timestamps and/or versions within the filenames of the different SQL files to control their order (plus these tools give you lots of other great features).